# Go to Definition not working Visual Studio 2019 Tried everything no luck

Tags: visual-studio, go-to-definition

I have visual studio 2019 version 16.4.5 in C# and up until a few days ago, everything was working fine. However this week I just can't go to any step definition unless I do a find in the project which is very time consuming on such a large project. I used to be able to F12 into any step definition I wanted so not sure where it's gone wrong. I haven't downloaded anything new recently which I think could affect it.

I have Resharper and Specflow installed and ensured they were up to date and followed various guides to ensure these have been set up correctly with the right options.

I have tried deleting the hidden .vs folder in hopes that might help but nothing.

I'm unable to delete and reinstall visual studio 2019 as I do not have admin rights.

Everything checks out but I'm not sure what else to try. Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Actually ReSharper supports Ctrl+click to go to definition which I find more useful, but anyway if you want to restore F12 behaviour you should check Options->Environment->Keyboard-> Find 'Edit.GoToDefinition' command and assign F12 to it.

Comment: Try deleting all .user files, and resetting the VS keyboard (Tools|Customize|Keyboard|Reset), and the Resharper keyboard (Resharper|Keyboard|Apply Scheme).

Comment: @bashis thank you, it looks like my keyboard already has F12 assigned to it. I can't even do a Ctrl+click from the feature page. Might be worth mentioning even if I do a right click and select Go to definition from the list, I get a binding issue - says the step definition doesnt exist